# How do I convert a pdf with mathematical typesetting to work on a Kindle Fire 7?

Tags: pdf, conversion, kindle-fire

There is a [website](https://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/) for a free ebook in PDF format.  See this section:

Order a copy from Amazon or Barnes & Noble for $16.46 or download a PDF for free here. Click HERE for a PDF copy of the entire book, or get the chapters individually below.

I tried downloading the book as a PDF file and attaching it to an email addressed to my_user_name@kindle.com with the subject line 'convert'.  It converted to something I could read on my Kindle Fire 7, except the mathematical text was all garbled.

Is there a better way to convert the PDF so that the mathematical typesetting is legible on a Kindle Fire 7?

I have read sometimes that mathematical typesetting in a PDF needs to be converted into images for this to be possible?